# Getting 503 after 30 sec with nginx and node js app in docker env

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket, timeout, akka

i am getting **503 service unavailable** immediately after 30 sec on browser console while exporting user details (React app)

to reproduce this issue i have added `Thread.sleep(30000)` at akka http end in test api.

I have alredy fine tune all timeout setting at akkka server and nginx - > default.conf file as below :

```
 proxy_read_timeout 100;
 proxy_connect_timeout 100;
 proxy_send_timeout 100;
```

but still its not work for me.
there is no issue with backend like CPU, memory usage. api is working fine as i have tested this with curl command.

NOTE: on my local machine its works fine, this issue coming with docker and nginx env on TETS site.
Nginx version: 1.20.1  (updated to latest one)

Could you please help me for the same ?

Comment: Have you looked into why your backend is taking abnormally wrong to serve the request?  This is normal behavior in Nginx if the backend accepts a request but never produces a response.

Comment: Thanks David, yes i have checked there is no such abnormal execution for that API, this API is just exporting all users with all details (76 column) in csv file, which takes 1.2min, but before that i am getting 503 service unavailable. please suggest any way to increase wait time for nginx

Comment: Actually this would rather be a 504 if caused by a slow backend IMHO. Any hints in the nginx log? Since you didn't specify a 30 seconds timeout anywhere in the nginx configuration I would guess this is more likely a problem in the backend service.